# making table calculations with results from sql query in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, html-table, calculation

I use table plugins on my WordPress site and I use a plugin that generates shortcode from PHP codes. These PHP codes I have done just make several SQL queries in a target WordPress DB table, such as the PHP code below (for several different 'stringname' values).

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$company = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM `wordpresstable` WHERE column='stringname'" );
echo $company->price;
?>
```

These queries return strings that are in fact numbers (prices). Then I want to make table calculations with some table values that I update manually and with the values from my shortcodes (prices). I can get my strings/numbers from my shortcodes to be displayed in my table, so far so good. However the problem arises when I try to make calculations with thes values returned from my shortcodes. It simply won't work and I even get an error. It seems that the SQL calls are actually done AFTER the rendering of the table. As the error refers to a type issue, I tried to use the function floatval() in my PHP shortcode (echo floatval($company->price)) for the returned value but it did not help. I think I am missing something obivious.

Any idea/waiver? Thanks. (Here are 2 screenshots with a simple example)

My Tablepress frontend with the shortcode in cell E2
[image: My Tablepress frontend with the shortcode in cell E2]

The table rendering in the web page, indicating a type error
[image: The table rendering in the web page, indicating a type error]

Comment: You can use json_decode to convert your string output to the integer. After that you can make use of it in your expression.

Comment: Hi, I changed echo $company->price; to echo json_decode($company->price, true);. I now have 5.11 instead of 5.1100 but still, delta% where D2 = E2 won't show E2 value.